# Get Smart Contract instance from its address

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

In Solidity, given a Smart Contract instance named `foo`

```js
MySmartContract foo = new MySmartContract()
```

I can get this Smart Contract instance's address by using `address(foo)`

```js
address fooAdress = address(foo)
```

How do I get back `foo` object, given only its address `fooAdress`?

I expect something like:

```js
MySmartContract originalFoo = some_function_goes_here(fooAdress)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need the interface of the contract too. If you do not have a contract code and you want to call contract methods but if you do not have the code how would you know which methods to call?

```
interface InterfaceA {
    function count() external view returns (uint256);
    function increment() external;
}
```

you know the address of the contract

```
InterfaceA a = InterfaceA(addressA);
```

`a` is the contract instance

- If you know only the address you can use `address.call` but this is not Safe ant Not recommended. You need to know the selector of the function. For example if you have "transfer" function

  ```
      // we need function name and its argument types (address and uint256)
      bytes4 private constant TRANSFER_SELECTOR = bytes4(keccak256(bytes('transfer(address,uint256)')));
  ```

then

```
// abi.encodeWithSignature() method is the standard way to interact with contracts
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = contractAddress.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(TRANSFER_SELECTOR, to, value));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the "object", unless your intent is to get the bytecode of the contract. In that case `some_function_goes_here` is `fooAddress.code`.

MySmartContract is really just an address under the hood. It's a convenient way to specify the ABI protocol for that address. Without it, if you wanted to call a function in foo, you'd have to do `foo.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("someFunction"))` which is a lot less convenient.

If your intent is to get a public variable from `foo`, you can just do `foo.someVariable()`.